# When the project builds the following error is shown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

When I build my application and makes it run, the following error message is shown

> The following module was build either
>   with optimization enabled or without
>   debug information. To debug thid
>   module change its project build
>   configuration to Debug mode.To
>   suppress this message, disable the
>   'warn if no user code on launch'
>   debugger option.

How to get rid of this error. Can anybody suggest.

Comment: The error itself says "To suppress this message, disable the 'warn if no user code on launch' debugger option."

Comment: but it doesn't work ok!!

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the error message is that you have one or more library compiled in release mode when starting the application in debug mode. So, to get rid of the message, you can:

- make sure that all libraries are compiled in debug mode,
- start in release mode instead, or
- disable the error message as specified in the error message.

You can still debug code that is compiled in release mode, but as the code is not compiled with debugging in mind, you may experience that it's not possible to put a breakpoint on any line, or that statements are not executed in the exact order that they are written in the code.